# ErrorCode=DelimitedTextMoreColumnsThanDefined

Tags: csv, delimiter, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I'm actually working with the Comma(,) delimited csv file, trying to perform copy activity.

One column contains json data like below

```
"{""allow"":"""",""deny"":"""",""description"":""Public"",""friends"":"""",""value"":""EVERYONE""}"
```

So when we process the data, the columns are shifting and we are getting the below error.

[image]

What should be on the source and sink escape and quote characters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To me, looks like your escape char and quote char are " (double quote). Did you try that?